# Webpack error during vuejs with cypress for e2e test

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, faker.js

I am sorry for my bad English skill. I try to write e2e test for vuejs. I am using cypress for that. But there is a problem. This problem is a webpack error. The error occurs after import a thirdy package.

My cypress test:

```
      import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

      const username = faker.internet.userName();
      const password = faker.internet.password();
      it('form elements should be correct', () => {
        cy.get(userLoginElement.username).type(username).should('have.value', username);
        cy.get(userLoginElement.password).type(password).should('have.value', password);
        cy.get(userLoginElement.loginButton).should('exist');
      });
```

My cypress.json file:

```
{
  "pluginsFile": "tests/e2e/plugins/index.js",
  "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
}
```

My plugin file of cypress

```
 module.exports = (on, config) => {
  return Object.assign({}, config, {
    fixturesFolder: 'tests/e2e/fixtures',
    integrationFolder: 'tests/e2e/specs',
    screenshotsFolder: 'tests/e2e/screenshots',
    videosFolder: 'tests/e2e/videos',
    supportFile: 'tests/e2e/support/index.js'
  })
}
```

My versions of the packages:

```
"faker": "^6.6.6",
 "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0",
 "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
"cypress": "^8.3.0",
```

Throw below error after running **vue-cli-service test:e2e**

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/@faker-js/faker/dist/esm/chunk-4J2PVEV7.mjs 1:1430
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:1430)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

May it be the version that reasons of the error ?

Edit:

There is a thread opened for this problem. [Here](https://github.com/faker-js/faker/issues/1073)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the latest version of `faker-js` will not work with Cypress.

Notice the Cypress documentation [here](https://learn.cypress.io/advanced-cypress-concepts/database-initialization-and-seeding) shows an old way of importing the faker library:

```js
import faker from "faker" // NOTE - no longer valid for recent versions of faker-js
```

The latest version of `@faker-js/faker` is @7.2.0, if you down-grade to @6.3.0 the spec will work.

```js
npm remove @faker-js/faker 
npm install @faker-js/faker@6.3.0 --save-dev
```

or with `yarn`

```js
yarn remove @faker-js/faker 
yarn add @faker-js/faker@6.3.0 -D
```

**Test**

```js
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';     // import is ok with version @6.3.0
```

---

#### Plugin to resolve for @faker-js/faker@7.2.0 (Cypress v9 cconfig)

This addition for `cypress/plugins/index.js` will allow the latest version of faker to work.

```js
const webpackPreprocessor = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");

module.exports = (on) => {
  const options = webpackPreprocessor.defaultOptions;
  options.webpackOptions.module.rules[0].exclude = {
    and: [/node_modules/],
    not: [/@faker-js/],
  };
  options.webpackOptions.resolve = {
    alias: {
      "@faker-js/faker": require.resolve("@faker-js/faker"),
    },
  };

  on("file:preprocessor", webpackPreprocessor(options));

  // original content

  return Object.assign({}, config, {
    fixturesFolder: 'tests/e2e/fixtures',
    integrationFolder: 'tests/e2e/specs',
    screenshotsFolder: 'tests/e2e/screenshots',
    videosFolder: 'tests/e2e/videos',
    supportFile: 'tests/e2e/support/index.js'
  })
}
```

---

#### Update for Cypress version 10+ configuration

Note the Cypress docs around `webpack-preprocessor` still have the old configuration.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
const webpackPreprocessor = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");

const options = webpackPreprocessor.defaultOptions;
options.webpackOptions.module.rules[0].exclude = {
  and: [/node_modules/],
  not: [/@faker-js/],
};
options.webpackOptions.resolve = {
  alias: {
    "@faker-js/faker": require.resolve("@faker-js/faker"),
  },
};

export default defineConfig({

  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("file:preprocessor", webpackPreprocessor(options));
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I tried this and tests ran successfully. But another error occurred. Typescript shows a error after I import the faker package. Tests run with the error but I don't want there are any errors. Error says:
"TS2307: Cannot find module '@faker-js/faker' or its corresponding type declarations."

Comment: Has any relationships the error with settings of typescript ?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I will continue to use old version.

Comment: That's bad luck, it worked for me. What went wrong - maybe I can resolve it for you.

Comment: I restarted the project and fixed the error. It shows like there aren't any error here